# Google map is not visible in my mashup

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am completely new in map scripting so my question may be stupid, but i would love if you can answer this. The following is the code which i took from google map tutorials. When run the example, it works fine. but when I used it in my code, no map is visible.
here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>PGet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function invokeMap()
{


      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    //document.getElementById('form_container').innerHTML="";
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);


}

</script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" onload = "invokeMap()" >


 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>

<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload="invokeMap()" >
```

Make sure you remember to call the initialization function.

Comment: Didn't get your point. In the tutorial the function is named as intialization, here I called it invokemap. Is it illegal?

Comment: No you can call it whatever you like, just make sure you do call it. You didn't post the code where you called it, so I assumed you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

here is the same code as you written you only need is give proper tags. your `<body onload="invokeMap()" >` is correct. see this code

```
<html>    
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>PGet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function invokeMap()
{


      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    //document.getElementById('form_container').innerHTML="";
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);


}

</script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" onload = "invokeMap()" >


 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>

<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```